# Link to a page with modal opened already

Tags: html, url, hyperlink, modal-dialog

I have a web page with a gallery of products, and each product opens a modal with it's specific information. Each product modal has a unique id; however, when the modal is opened there is no change in the URL. Therefore, I have no way of linking someone to a specific opened product modal, only the page with the entire gallery.

I have looked into modifying the url to include the id, as well as attempting to create hyperlinks with onClick events that would trigger the opening of the modal upon clicking link. I am not sure if either method is possible.

Here is an example of my modal code:

```
<ul id="selectable">
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="1">
<li class="ui-state-gal"><b>Modal 1</b></br>
<img src="images/Products/gal/CT8002.png" width="45" height="94"></li>
</a>

<a href="#" data-reveal-id="2">
<li class="ui-state-gal"><b>Modal 2</b></br>
<img src="images/Products/gal/FF310.png" width="45" height="94"></li>
</a>
</ul>

<div id="1" class="reveal-modal">
CT8002
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="2" class="reveal-modal">
FF310
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: use different Model ID for different products!

Comment: "Each product modal has a unique id"

Answer (score 0):

Use different UNIQUE Model ID for different products!

For example:

Model Call

```
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="1a">
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="2b">
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="3c">
```

Model Data

```
<div id="1a" class="reveal-modal">
 Data A
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="2b" class="reveal-modal">
 Data B
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>

<div id="3c" class="reveal-modal">
 Data C
<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
```

In the example above, There are three different IDs. `1a, 2b and 3c` because it will load data with respect to ID defined to it and to that data.

I hope this helps you!